# Representing many to many model in django as json

Tags: python, json, django

I have the following django model.

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rules', null=True, blank=True)
    threshold = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    alert_value = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'threshold': self.threshold,
            'alert_value': self.alert_value
        }

class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rules = models.ManyToManyField(Rule)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
            'rules': self.rules
        } 

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

Now how do I code up the to_json method in module to accept many rules.

I am currently doing as

`response = [module.to_json() for module in modules if module.name is not None]`

and it throws an error telling.

`<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x10811c390> is not JSON serializable`

What is the best way to represent that as a json and iterate it over.

Comment: I think you don't need M2M there, a ForeignKey should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'rules': [r.to_json() for r in self.rules.all()]
```

Comment: When I get the rules it prints an empty list

Comment: Do you get an empty list when inspecting the same object in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

The way that the `dumpdata` management command does it with fixtures is to dump an array of the PK values for the objects in the ManyToMany field.  The instances themselves are dumped separately.

For example:

```
 {
    "pk": 365,
    "model": "tree.tree",
    "fields": {
        "label": "Root",
        "subtrees": [
            367,
            368
         ]
 }
```

I'd start by looking into that implementation and see what, if anything, you can reuse from it.